# Java Regex find word with no = on end

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently struggling with a text parser to format java protected words with there own HTML tags.

so I want

```
class HelloWorld
```

To appear as a string

```
<span class= "class">class</span> HelloWorld
```

Which I managed to get working, however class is a protected word, so I want to be able to distinquish using regex beween

```
class
```

and

```
"class" or class=
```

Here is my current code.

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\b"+javaWord+"\\b",addTag(javaWord,javaWord));
```

Really struggling so appreciate any help?

Comment: Don't also forget fun cases such as `String x = "I don't want to go to class today."`

Comment: Regex isn't entirely the right tool for this. There are lot of existing syntax highlighters. Why reinvent your own?

Comment: @grayamorris you should accept the answer by Alan as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `"\\b"+javaWord+"\\b"`, try

```
"(?<![\\w\"])"+javaWord+"(?![\\w\"=])"
```

But @sgusc makes a good point: this technique can't be extended to deal with keywords in longer string literals, or in comments either.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, I'm having real trouble getting to grips with regular expressions. I really need to spend more time on it.

Answer (score 0):

you're better off creating your own state machine that iterates over the input, each time you see whitespace (or just non alphabetic chars) you then flush the buffer depending on what word you just passed

so that when you pass a `"` you ignore until the next (unescaped) `"` (same with `<` and `>`) (or just see it as one word with `<span class="string">` around it ;)

Comment: This sound very interesting as my code is not working well, neither is it reusable. I'd really like to have a go at the state machine to replace my current code. Do you have any tutorials you'd recommended or any more information I could use to get started?

Comment: @gary if it's a simple parser it's just a while/for loop that, add each letter to a string builder and on each non alfabetic char do something special